# Cron schedule expression for running every 30 mins for first 7 days of every month, every two hours after that

Tags: cron

So far I have this: `0 */30 0 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 * ?` but not sure how to express every two hours after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would look something like that:

```
*/30 * 1-7 * * command
* */2 8-31 * * command
```

Where the first cron runs every 30 minutes for the first 7 days of the month, and the second one runs every 2 hours from day 8 onwards.